# How to disable Windows Gamebar mapping?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been a happy Gridmove user for years, and I use the combination <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to change into the "send window to grid location" mode. Now I got a new work computer with Windows 10, and when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, it pulls up a small window asking me "Is this a game?". I have to click on the grid entry window to return focus to it, which introduces a lot of friction in the wrong place.

I won't play games on this computer, and if I did, I don't see why I would want a "game bar" anyway. How do I tell Windows to forget its shortcut mapping of this combination so I can use it for Gridmove?

I am not just asking how to add a new mapping. The mapping I need is already added by GridMove. But the problem is that both get invoked and the function started by the Windows mapping takes precedence.

Comment: I don't think the solution from the linked "duplicate" question will work for me. It explains how to make the mapping the OP wants. The Windows + G combination is already mapped by GridMove, it is just that both mappings get invoked and the Windows one takes precedence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that there is a registry key for that.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR

`AppCaptureEnabled DWORD` should be set to 0 and

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore

`GameDVR_Enabled DWORD` should be set to 0.

[This site](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8637-game-bar-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) offers a .reg file which will change it when open with the registry editor.

Comment: Having uninstalled the Xbox app, I just had to add the first registry value; the following does so in an elevated Powershell console: `New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR -Name AppCaptureEnabled -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD` .

Answer (score 2):

Its easy. Just open Xbox app from start menu. Then visit settings from left, and pick Game DVR tab. In top you will see "Record game clips and screenshots using Game DVR" - so, just disable it and all will be fine :)

Good luck :)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. When I search for Xbox in the start menu and highlight it, there is a "settings" button to the left, but it only shows the Cortana settings when I click it, and there is no "Game DVR" tab. When I actually open the Xbox app, it has a single "Sign in" button and no settings button at all.

Comment: Yes, all settings u need is in that Xbox App... So, try to sign in first... the menu will appear then. Notify when you do that :)

Comment: Thank you. I upvoted your answer, but I dislike the idea of creating an account to some service just because I have to turn off a feature of my OS I will never use. Luckily, it turned out that it can be edited in the registry too, see my answer.

Comment: @RumiP. yes, maybe u are right... but without login, u cant download apps from store and etc. Its same like your android/ios phone. So... it is not big deal :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the registry key edits listed in [Rumi P.’s answer](//superuser.com/q/1096724/354511#1097169) to turn off the Game Bar in Windows 10 when playing World of Warcraft. None of them worked.

I did find a different key that worked, however:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\GameBar
```

In there I found an entry for `ShowStartupPanel`.  I changed the `DWORD` value to `0` and voilà – no more annoying game bar message in WoW.