# Xbox Game bar after uninstalling UWP and disabling UAC

Tags: windows-10

It looks like the [Creator's](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3185756/windows/windows-10-creators-update-the-5-biggest-changes.html) update [pushed out and/or reset new stuff](http://windowsreport.com/creators-update-xbox-one/) from Microsoft.

I have [uninstalled](https://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/) and [disabled](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3f6h4d/cant_open_microsoft_edge_while_uac_is_off/) UWPs as much as I can, along with Cortana and Edge.  Yet today I saw a weird green bar popup saying something about "Press Win + G to bring up the game bar".  I figured it would have to do with the Xbox UWP app, which I have previously uninstalled.  I presume this is UWP functionality, but I'm not sure how to find out for certain.

Can this app or program exist outside of the UWP ecosystem?  Is it a part of the Xbox app?  What method(s) are there to remove it?  Is there a prophylactic to prevent such things in the future?

I'm currently stuck in Windows Home, even though I [tried to upgrade to Pro](https://community.dell.com/thread/23933-clean-install-of-windows-10-pro) (not me, but gives you context).  I will be fixing that sometime soon.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this app or program exist outside of the UWP ecosystem?

The `Game DVR` feature and specifically the in-game `Game Bar` that appears in compatible applications, is controlled by the Xbox Universal Windows Platform application, which is one of the default provisioned UWP applications.

> Is it a part of the Xbox app?

Yes

> What method(s) are there to remove it?

In order to disable the Game DVR you have to disable it within the Xbox application.

> ### How to Disable Game DVR (and the Game Bar)
>
> Unlike most Windows 10 features, which can be configured in the
>   Settings app, the Game DVR and Game Bar features are buried in the
>   Xbox app.
>
> 1. Launch the Xbox app from your Start menu.
>
>    - You’ll need sign in with a Microsoft account if you haven’t already.
> 2. Once you’re signed into the Xbox app, click the gear-shaped Settings button at the bottom-left corner of the app and then click
>      “Game DVR”.
> 3. Disable the “Record game clips and take screenshots using Game DVR” option at the top of the screen. This will disable background
>      recording, the Game Bar, and other Game DVR features.
> 4. Game DVR, including background recording and the Game Bar, will now remain disabled unless you return to the Xbox app and enable it.
>
> [image]

Source: [How to Disable Windows 10’s Game DVR (and Game Bar)](https://www.howtogeek.com/273180/how-to-disable-windows-10s-game-dvr-and-game-bar/)

> Is there a prophylactic to prevent such things in the future?

Once you disable the Game DVR functionality it will stay disabled.

> How do I disable UAC on Windows 10 Home?

In order to turn UAC competely, open regedit, and navigate to following location.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

You are going to have to modify the value of **EnableLUA** to 0.  Setting the UAC setting to it's lowest setting, within the Control Panel on Windows 10, does not actually disable UAC.

Answer (score 0):

> Yet today I saw a weird green bar popup saying something about "Press Win + G to bring up the game bar".

I'm not sure if I was having the same problem; I wanted to use Win + G with AutoHotkey and had the problem of getting a pop-up when I pressed it. (I had uninstalled the Xbox app.) I first landed at the question [How to disable Windows Gamebar mapping?](https://superuser.com/questions/1096724/how-to-disable-windows-gamebar-mapping), which claims to be a duplicate of this one. Making the first registry change according to [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1097169/771743) allowed me to use Win + G without triggering a popup. Here is the PowerShell command to make the requisite change; it requires you to "Run as Administrator":

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR -Name AppCaptureEnabled -Value 0 -PropertyType DWORD
```

The original source of this change is 
[Turn On or Off Game Bar in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8637-turn-off-game-bar-windows-10-a.html); you can download a .reg file if you prefer to make the registry change that way. If this does not solve the problem in the OP, then the other question I referenced is most definitely *not* a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 0):

running this in PowerShell as administrator worked for me on Windows 11:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay | Remove-AppxPackage
```

credits to https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-uninstall-xbox-game-bar-on-windows-pc for the solution