# How to complete disable/remove Gameoverlay?

Tags: windows, gaming, xbox-game-dvr

I'm currently facing this(please see the attached image) annoying pop-up everytime I open a game.

[image: gameoverlay]

My question is how to completely remove/disable this pop-up? I have already tried >> Go to Settings > Gaming > Game Bar. Then turn off "record game clips, screenshots, and broadcast using Game bar".

**Is there any gpedit or regedit hack or app or anything to fix this pop-up?**

<< heads up information >>

I'm using a custom Windows 11 which I created using MSMG toolkit and already removed the Xbox all apps and services including game bar, MS store app, Xbox dependencies etc.. from the original ISO to create my custom Windows 11 ISO.

Why can't Microsoft create the environment which was simple and just click and run Windows 7 style without additional apps and services.

Comment: I'm using a custom Windows 11     ......... Try removing with power shell.

Comment: theres nothing to remove(tried already), it was already removed when creating the custom ISO.

Comment: Nothing you can do then except live with the overlay.

Comment: I specifically remember submitting an answer nearly 2 years ago, assosicate with this very behavior, but I can't find it since neither this question nor the original question actually has the text "ms-gamingoverlay" contained in the body.

Comment: There appear to be many things that have worked for many people.  I suspect that this is because you stripped things MS didn't count on being gone.  There are quite a bit of different solutions that have worked for different people on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8b59bo/youll_need_a_new_app_to_open_this_msgamingoverlay/) reddit post.

Comment: I [found](https://superuser.com/questions/1670249/you-will-need-a-new-app-to-open-this-windows-defender-link/1670370#1670370) the original question I had answered. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1096724/how-to-disable-windows-gamebar-mapping/1097169#1097169) is likely a better answer.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound for sharing the regedit hack, it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @Ramhound for sharing the answer hence posting it here. The regedit hack worked fine. Here's the link for that answer >> [How to disable Windows Gamebar mapping?](https://superuser.com/questions/1096724/how-to-disable-windows-gamebar-mapping/1097169#1097169)